# ASP.NET Core InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type DbContext while attempting to activate UserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have this DbContext in my Application which uses IdentityDbContext

```
public class ShopDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>, IDisposable
    {


        public ShopDbContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
        {            
            Products = base.Set<Product>();
            Categories = base.Set<Category>();
            Shops = base.Set<Shop>();
            Properties = base.Set<Property>();
            Orders = base.Set<Order>();
            OrderItems = base.Set<OrderItem>();
            Customers = base.Set<Customer>();
            Carts = base.Set<Cart>();
            CartItems = base.Set<CartItem>();
            UserShops = base.Set<UserShop>();
            Images = base.Set<Image>();

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            // Use singular table names
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Product>(new ProductConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Category>(new CategoryConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Shop>(new ShopConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Property>(new PropertyConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Order>(new OrderConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<OrderItem>(new OrderItemConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Customer>(new CustomerConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Cart>(new CartConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<CartItem>(new CartItemConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<UserShop>(new UserShopConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<Image>(new ImageConfiguration());
        }

        public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Property> Properties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserShop> UserShops { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }

    }
```

And this is my User model:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
        public Guid ShopId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastActive { get; set; }
        public List<UserShop> UserShopList { get; set; }
        public bool HasImage()
        {
            return Guid.Empty != ImageId;
        }
    }
```

And the Startup code is like below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContextFactory<ShopDbContext>(builder => 
            builder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ShopDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddSqlServerDbContextFactory<ShopDbContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IShopEFRepository, EFRepository<ShopDbContext>>();

        Shop.Core.Configure.Configure.ConfigureServices(services);
        services.AddScoped<IUpdateService, UpdateService>();
        //services.AddSingleton<IBotService, BotService>();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                        .GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero //the default for this setting is 5 minutes
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                        {
                            context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            options.AddPolicy("User", policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));
            options.AddPolicy("ShopManager", policy => policy.RequireRole("Manager"));
            options.AddPolicy("DeviceRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Device"));
            options.AddPolicy("OwnerRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Owner"));
        });

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
            {
                opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                    Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
        //services.AddCors();            
        Mapper.Reset();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
       // loggerFactory.AddMongoFramework<InfoLog>(ServiceProvider);
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (error != null)
                    {
                        context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Moreover I use [EFCore.DbContextFactory](https://github.com/vany0114/EF.DbContextFactory) for my generic repository. When I try to build the database I get exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
        Shop.SQLData.ShopDbContext while attempting to activate
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore Shop.SqlModel.User,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Shop.SQLData.ShopDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]].
```

I think the problem is in the way I set the DbContextFactory but As I followed the examples provided with it I did the same approach.

Besides, my connection string is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "User ID=sa; Password=123456;Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=ShopDb;"
  }
```

When I try to generate the database using Package Manager update-database I get this error:

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public ShopDbContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
```

try change it to this

```
 public ShopDbContext(DbContextOptions<ShopDbContext> options): base(options)
```

and change it

```
 services.AddDbContextFactory<ShopDbContext>(builder => 
            builder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
```

to this

```
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContextFactory<DbContext,ShopDbContext>(builder => 
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Comment: Dudu, you pass into you dbContext not connectionString like "User ID=sa; Password=123456;Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=ShopDb;",  you just pass "DefaultConnection" (it is not connectionString it just section in your appSettings file)

Comment: how does this work? isn't the second type parameter of `AddDbContextFactory` supposed to be a factory? ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextfactory?view=efcore-7.0)) when I try to implement this in my code I get type errors saying there is no reference conversion from `ShopDbContext` to `IDbContextFactory<DbContext>`

Comment: Can you send your code or may be link on github

Comment: yeah here's [the repo I'm working on](https://github.com/fmbot-discord/fmbot)

Comment: I don't know, is that a bad idea? I didn't write that part of the code, I'm just trying to understand it. if it's an anti-pattern and the best path forward is to change it I'm ok with that @evilGenius

Comment: No i watch doc again and it's ok. But you said about get exception with ShopDbContext. I see only FMBotDbContext. Can you put here text of the exception. Because if you reg context as in example then you can get IDbContextFactory as dependency and then may createDbContext which you need